# show the bars in matpolib

Tags: plot, bar-chart

i tried to show two bars but the nubmer are too low and the bar didnt show
[image]

```
def plot(self,filename):
    boys_correct_arrow,boys_wrong_arrow,boys_correct_color,boys_wrong_color,girls_correct_arrow,girls_wrong_arrow,girls_correct_color,girls_wrong_color = self.analyze_data(filename)
    X = ['Average of correct answers arrow task','Average of wrong answers arrow task','Average of correct answers color task','Average of wrong answers color task']
    dict = {
        "Boys": [boys_correct_arrow,boys_wrong_arrow,boys_correct_color,boys_wrong_color],
        "Girls":[girls_correct_arrow,girls_wrong_arrow,girls_correct_color,girls_wrong_color]
    }
    X_axis = np.arange(len(X))
    mul = 0
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')
    for i,j in dict.items():
        temp1 = 0.4*mul
        temp2 = ax.bar(X_axis+temp1,j,0.4,label=i)
        ax.bar_label(temp2,padding=3)
        mul+=1
    ax.set_xticks(X_axis+0.4,X)
    ax.legend(loc='upper left', ncols=2)
    plt.show()
```